# ANE-NativeWebView - How do I set up the encoding?

Tags: ane

I can't get the Cyrillic alphabet to display correctly in any way

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTAoJ.png)
tell me what to do?

I tried to specify parameters in the html itself - but it didn't help. ( ааа 123 )